# how to set value in 2 cell if other cell contains 'something'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have some pandas dataframe:

```
a,b,c
AAA,,
DDD,,
KKK,,
AAA,,
```

I want to search in column "A" and if string in column "A" contains word "AAA" I need set value "BBB" in column "B"  and "CCC" in column "C".
So, I want to get result as following:

```
a,b,c
AAA,BBB,CCC
DDD,,
KKK,,
AAA,BBB,CCC
```

I wrote the code with numpy:

```
df['b'] = pd.np.where(df.a.str.contains("AAA"), "BBB", '')
```

How to extend it to work with 'b' and 'c' columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use double `np.where`:

```
mask = df.a.str.contains("AAA")
df['b'] = pd.np.where(mask, "BBB", '')
df['c'] = pd.np.where(mask, "CCC", '')
```

Or [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
mask = df.a.str.contains("AAA")
df = df.assign(b=pd.np.where(mask, "BBB", ''), c=pd.np.where(mask, "CCC", ''))
```

If need create multiple columns with one `np.where` is necessary create `Nx1` mask:

```
mask = df.a.str.contains("AAA")[:, None]
df[['b','c']] = np.where(mask, ['BBB','CCC'], ['',''])
print (df)
     a    b    c
0  AAA  BBB  CCC
1  DDD          
2  KKK          
3  AAA  BBB  CCC
```

Comment: What should I change if I want 2 or more variants for search in string? For example "AAA" or "DDD" or "KKK"?

Comment: @j.stalin - DO you think `mask = df.a.str.contains("AAA|DDD|KKK")` ?

Comment: Thanks again, this is what I need

Comment: One more question, how can I change the cells i needed and DON'T change others? I

Comment: @j.stalin - I think need `df = df.assign(b=pd.np.where(mask, "BBB", df.a), c=pd.np.where(mask, "CCC", df.a))`